# Remote file download using .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'm trying to download remote file using C# (ASP.NET). The problem is when I browse to the file download URL - it downloads perfectly. When I try the WebClient.DownloadData(url) I get "no data to show" response.

If I browse using the built-in VS2010 browser I still get this "error" message.

The file link is: http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/Pages/Export.aspx?sn=he-IL_ds&enumTblType=AllSecurities&Columns=he-IL_Columns&Titles=he-IL_Titles&TblId=0&ExportType=3
(CSV file)

How can the file be downloaded? any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: When I click on that link in my browser (FF), I get “No data to show”, so it might be based on session as Nick said.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a download problem on *your* side, that page is referencing something, probably from session...so you would need to login to the site, get a session, basically go through whatever steps you normally would in route to getting the file so it's generated correctly/available.

If I had to take a guess, I'm thinking they do the export to the file system when you ask for it, so it's a temp file somewhere...not something you can just grab, so unless you went through the step that created it (doesn't seem this Export.aspx page does it), it won't be there, and their error message for this is "No data to show".

There's also the possibility they're explicitly blocking you to prevent any kind of bots/leeching from happening...basically preventing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: But that's strange - if you try to browse to that page, without authentication of any kind, you get to download the file.
So my guess there are no sessions there - just some kind of blockage?

Comment: @Roman - There might be, blocking by referrer to prevent leeching I'd guess, it's a pretty common hot-linking counter-measure.

Comment: If it was so, wouldn't they block direct-browsing download? If I'd browse directly to the link - they'd have no referrer and thus would block me. wouldn't they?

Comment: @Roman - it *is* blocked here, are you sure you don't have a session in whatever browser you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Many sites will block downloads based on the Referer or User-Agent header.

1. Watch a "working" download with
   [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)
2. Watch your code's
   download with Fiddler
3. Compare the
   two requests
4. Update your request
   to match the "working" case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by obtaining the remote file as a stream. From that point I was able to read/write the stream to the response.

```
//The absolute path to your file
string remoteFile = "http://my.cloudfront.net/videos/vehicle_english_v3.mp4";

//The name of the file you want the user to see when they download the file
int pos = remoteFile.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
string fileName = remoteFile.Substring(pos, remoteFile.Length - pos);

//Obtain your file as a stream
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFile);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream fileStream = response.GetResponseStream();

//Write the stream to the response
if (fileStream != null && fileStream.CanRead) {
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    fileStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```